# Why am I getting Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header()?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a the latest version of WordPress installed into my htdocs folder. I try to visit the page by going to http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/newtheme/front-page.php and it gives me the error.

> Error: Call to undefined function get_header()?

I've looked through all of the questions and most of them say to install WordPress locally which I obviously have done. I reinstalled it thinking I might have a bad install. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm assuming this is why my CSS themes aren't showing when I visit the site in the dashboard as well but if anyone has an answer for that too that would be great.

header.php:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>

<head>
    
    <?php wp_head();?>

</head>

<body <?php body_class();?>>





<header class="sticky top">

</header>
```

functions.php

```
<?php

function load_stylesheets()
{

wp_register_style('bootstrap', 
get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' 
, array (), false, 'all');
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');

wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() 
. 'style.css' , array (), false, 'all');
wp_enqueue_style('style');



}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_stylesheets');



function include_jquery()
{

wp_deregister_script('jquery');

wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', '', 1, true);

add_action('p_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery');
    
    
}






function loadjs()
{
wp_register_script('customjs', 
get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scritps.js', '', 1, 
true);
wp_enqueue_script('customjs');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadjs');
```

front-page.php

```
<div class="container pt-5 pb-5">
<h1><?php the_title();?></h1>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : 
the_post();?>


    <?php the_content();?>


<?php endwhile; endif;?>


</div>





<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: That's not how WordPress works, you don't visit the template page directly in the URL like you're trying to do. That is simply a template file that gets picked up and used by WordPress.

Comment: That’s what I thought but it’s not showing up when I “visit” the site in my dashboard. None of my CSS is showing

Comment: That's a separate problem and would probably require starting a different question. It feels like a lot of the issues you will run into will not be specific programming or use-case issues but rather inexperience with WordPress. Which is okay we all start somewhere but I would recommend you watch a video tutorial on YouTube setting up a WP site & theme from start to finish. It will be faster to invest some time learning the overall process instead of asking questions each time you get stuck.